# aws_lambda_alias create a new one and do not update the existant one

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

is there any way with terraform to create a new lambda alias if the name changeS and do not update the existing one when performing terraform apply

```
  resource "aws_lambda_alias" "test_lambda_alias" {
      name             = "my_alias"
      description      = "a sample description"
      function_name    = aws_lambda_function.lambda_function_test.arn
      function_version = "1"
    }
```